# Winform destructor getting called twice

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, destructor

I have a standard c++cli win32 winform application made from the VS2013 template.

The first call returns to a non-debugable location `"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll"`

The second returns right after `Application::Run(%instance);` in `Main()`:

```
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

PorjectName::UserClass instance;
Application::Run(%instance);
```

I don't think it's hurting anything but I am curious to know why this is happening.

Is this behavior inherent with the way winforms c++cli objects work? How can I figure out what's causing it?

I followed this guide: http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/application_visual_studio_2013.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   PorjectName::UserClass instance;
```

This is what caused it.  UserClass is a reference type, you normally declare a variable that stores the a reference to the object with the ^ hat.  But you didn't, you now invoke a pattern called ["stack semantics"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  It emulates the RAII pattern in native C++, the compiler automatically emits a call to the destructor at the closing brace.

This is not appropriate for a class that derives from Form or Control. Such objects are already automatically disposed, it happens after the window is closed.  So you see *two* calls to the destructor, the first one coming from Winforms and the second one coming from the hidden destructor call in your Main() function.

This is actually not a bug in managed code and in fact common on some kind of classes.  It is nearly unavoidable on classes that derive from Stream for example.  Keep in mind that it is the finalizer that plays the role that is equivalent to a native C++ destructor, `!classname` in C++/CLI syntax.  Nevertheless, pretty easy to shoot your leg off if you don't count on it.

Just write the code properly:

```
ProjectName::UserClass^ instance = gcnew ProjectName::UserClass;
Application::Run(instance);
```

Or

```
auto instance = gcnew ProjectName::UserClass;
Application::Run(instance);
```

Or

```
Application::Run(gcnew ProjectName::UserClass);
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense now, beautiful.